# Grails database-migration with property to be db agnostic

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

Is there a way in the Grails-database migration plugin to define properties in migration files to be able to define database agnostic migration, like it is possible in Liquibase?

I tried with:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
property([name:"boolean.type", value:"bit(1)",dbms:"mysql" ])
property([name:"boolean.type", value:"number(1,0)", dbms:"oracle"])
...
}
```

an using it in the colum definition:

```
changeSet(author: "me", id: "121112341-1") {
createTable(tableName: "test_table") {
...
column(name: "my_column", type: "${boolean.type}")
...
}
}
```

but that does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Groovy file `"${boolean.type}"` is a GString, so Groovy is attempting to resolve the property `type` of the variable `boolean`. You need to use single quotes so Groovy leaves the string alone and lets Liquibase do the dbms-specific replacement:

```
column(name: "my_column", type: '${boolean.type}')
```

Comment: That worked. Using the Callback bean I was able to rework all migration files during startup so they are really db agnostic. Currently I'm supporting MySQL and Oracle. Thanks Burt.