# Unneccessary database changeSet related to boolean after grails 2.4.3 upgrade

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I am using postgres database. After upgading to grails 2.4.3 I get database changeset of this type for all boolean fields:

```
changeSet(author: "me(generated)", id: "1383573084784-1") {
    addColumn(tableName: "chapter") {
        column(defaultValue: true, name: "is_framable", type: "boolean") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }
    }
}
```

`isFramable` is a `boolean` field in the domain class `Chapter`. Even after running this migration it's generated everytime by `dbm-gorm-diff`

I noticed that in older versions of grails there used to be `bool` instead of `boolean` in the changesets

I am using hibernate version 4.3.5.5

Comment: We have the same issue but no solution yet. We just ignore these entries...

Comment: This can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/14470586

Comment: I found what BOOLEAN field treated as BIT. http://postgresql.nabble.com/Wrong-SqlType-for-boolean-columns-td2256874.html

Answer (score 3):

My workaround for that:

*Config.groovy*

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    "user-type" type: my.hibernate.type.BooleanBitType, class: boolean
    "user-type" type: my.hibernate.type.BooleanBitType, class: Boolean
}
```

*BooleanBitType.java*

```
import my.hibernate.type.descriptor.BooleanBitTypeDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BooleanTypeDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.SqlTypeDescriptor;

public class BooleanBitType extends org.hibernate.type.BooleanType {
    public static final BooleanBitType INSTANCE = new BooleanBitType();

    public BooleanBitType() {
        this(BooleanBitTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, BooleanTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE);
    }

    protected BooleanBitType(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor, BooleanTypeDescriptor javaTypeDescriptor) {
        super(sqlTypeDescriptor, javaTypeDescriptor);
    }
}
```

*BooleanBitTypeDescriptor.java*

```
public class BooleanBitTypeDescriptor extends org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BooleanTypeDescriptor {
    public static final BooleanBitTypeDescriptor INSTANCE = new BooleanBitTypeDescriptor();

    public BooleanBitTypeDescriptor() {
        super();
    }

    public int getSqlType() {
        return Types.BIT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug still exists in grails 2.5.4 
Gets Postgres users badly b/c postgres has no equivalent bit datatype. It has a bit string which is not equivalent for holding boolean values.  The Grails docs suggest switching to char(1) Y/N version of boolean.

'user-type'(type: org.hibernate.type.YesNoType, class: Boolean)

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.4/ref/Database%20Mapping/Usage.html

However, I dislike the idea of bending my db schema to accommodate bugs in the app framework.

So, I'll probably just keep ignoring these unnecessary changesets.